# Are there really messages in the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one embed custom data in block headers?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-can-one-embed-custom-data-in-block-headers)

Someone told me a hacker put messages in the blockchain. What does this mean?

Edit: related asked/answered question

[How can one embed custom data in block headers?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18/custom-data-in-block-headers)

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate so that it can be merged into the other one.