# Is there a guaranteed hash for every block?

Tags: hash, algorithms, sha256, nonce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nonce size - Will it always be big enough?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/nonce-size-will-it-always-be-big-enough)

My question may be misphrased, if so, I'll correct it if you let me know in the comments.

My understanding of mining is that the header is appended with some `nonce` and that is SHA256'd to get some hash, let's say: `7050a40746c695a220acb99c725ef66b29aa863707b17ba939c8bb1f5ec52b67`

This happens until there are X number of consecutive 0's in that hash. Is there a guarantee that there will always be at least X 0's in a row for every block header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no guarantee that you can solve a block just by adjusting the `nonce`.  But there are other things you can change in a block that also change the hash.

[This question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1781/659) is pretty much an exact duplicate of your question.