# How can we look at the hidden message in the first block?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, genesis-block

[This is the first block](https://blockchain.info/block/000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f), how can I see the message?

> 'The Times 03/Jan/2009 Chancellor on brink of second bailout for banks'

Comment: related: [How can one embed custom data in block headers?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/18/5406)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on [the sole transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b) in that block (4a5e1e4b...) and click [Show scripts & coinbase](https://blockchain.info/tx/4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b?show_adv=true).

Comment: how did he do that? I thought OP_RETURN was only added later and that before the only way to do it was to encode data as a fake address in a transaction

Comment: @s.matthew.english: See http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20721/what-is-the-format-of-the-coinbase-transaction.  Because this is a generation transaction, it has a single input whose script is ignored.  The message takes the place of that script.

Comment: How can I get it through bitcoin-cli, I've tried `bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b true`, and return an error telling me that this is the genesis block and transaction whin it can't be retrieved.

Comment: @buzhidao: Yeah, I suspect that you just can't.  This is a special case for backward compatibility: the original release of Bitcoin had a bug where the coinbase transaction of the genesis block was not added to the utxo database, thus making it unspendable.  Every version since had to keep that behavior; otherwise, if Satoshi ever tried to spend those coins, it would cause a hard fork of the blockchain, as some clients would accept the transaction and others would reject it.